# INSERT tuple into table - psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to figure out how is it possible to insert a tuple of values into a predefined table without the need of the trivial syntax like :

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)",
...      (100, "abc'def"))
```

since i have the tuple with the correct sequence of values like below :

```
my_tuple = ('D', 'Z107383320', '99501', '995013688', None, '36', '88', '36', '88', 'A', 'F', 'C083', '', 'BARROW', 'ST', '', '0000000605', '0000000605', 'O', 'DOCTORS COLLECTIONS SVC', 'STE', '00000001', '00000001', 'O', 'B', '', '', '020312', 'AK', '020', 'AL', '', '', 'Z10014', 'zip4mst9')
```

i was wondering for some easy solution :-) like :

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (*) VALUES (*)",
    ...      (my_tuple))
```

Since i have the table schema created and tuple has the same sequence of attributes i suppose this is something possible to do without the hassle of passing all the arguments one by one to cur.execute()

Comment: The whole point of specifying the columns is not breaking all your queries when you add a new column to your table. That said, if you like being lazy, you should consider an ORM such as SQLAlchemy. Also, don't put the parentheses around `(my_tuple)` - they don't do anything (you already have a tuple, and also tuples are created by the comma, not by parentheses)

Answer (score 3):

Using this table

```
create table t (
    a int,
    b text
);
```

Omit the column list and pass the tuple as a single value

```
query = """
    insert into t values %s
    returning *
"""
my_tuple = (2, 'b')

cursor.execute(query, (my_tuple,)) # Notice the comma after my_tuple
rs = cursor.fetchall()
conn.commit()
for row in rs:
    print row
```

Prints

```
(2, 'b')
```

With the above done it looks to me as bad practice to not explicitly list the columns

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I agree it is bad practice but if you attempting to insert into an arbitrary table (as I am) than it is much more work to get the field names and place those in the query.  Thanks!

Comment: Why I am getting this error? AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
t = (100, "abc'def")
```

then:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (" + ",".join(["%s"]*len(t)) + ")"
cur.execute(sql, t)
```

i.e. repeat the placeholder once per field, comma separated.

Yes, it's ugly, but there's no magic "all parameters" wildcard. Perhaps there should be.

Comment: getting error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys' when trying this solution.

Comment: @JuanPerez You're probably using a newer psycopg2 version, where you must explicitly ask for record-like tuples if you want them using its dictionary-like cursor: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor

Answer (score -1):

query will continue to use %s
you can do like below

tuple_ex = (value1, value2)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute(query, tuple_ex)